# Multiple model.save's in 1 if condition with an unless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to save a `response` and also save an `issue` if it's not `nil` in one condition so i don't have multiple if/else conditions complicating this logic.

For the use case where `@response` exists and `issue` is nil, this does not get into the if block.

Is there something obvious that i'm not seeing or can I not write my logic in one line like this?

Note: I know a transaction should be used, but i'm just trying to get a working prototype up right now.

```
  if @response.save && (issue.save unless issue.nil?)  # Does not get into the if block when @response exists and issue is nil
    p 'in save'
    format.html { redirect_to issue_path(params[:issue_id]), notice: success_message }
  else
    p 'not in save'
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
  end
```

This is what I have working now and I was hoping there was an easier 1 liner rather than this.

```
success = false

if issue.nil?
  if @response.save
    success = true
  end
else
  if @response.save && issue.save
    success = true
  end
end

if success
  p 'in save'
  format.html { redirect_to issue_path(params[:issue_id]), notice: success_message }
else
  p 'not in save'
  format.html { render action: 'new' }
end
```

Comment: I think what you want with your code is `@response.save and (issue.nil? or issue.save)`. So it will execute the "success" condition when `@response.save` succeeds and either `issue` is `nil`, or if it is not `nil`, it saved successfully. I just saw your edit, it seems I was right ;)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Write that as an answer and not a comment because it works and that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: alright, posted as an answer then :) Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to execute the "success" condition when:

1. `@response.save` succeeded AND
2. `issue` is `nil` OR `issue` is not `nil` and it saved successfully.

Thus, you can just do;

```
if @response.save and (issue.nil? or issue.save)
  # Success
else 
  # Fail
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `&&` after `@response.save`, in case of issue.nil? the issue is not saved and returns a nil, which always causes it to give you a nil. I hope this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. So since issue is nil, that condition of the if clause returns false and therefore the entire if condition fails.

Comment: Yes that is the case!